# How to check column name already consists in table

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

I have the following two datatables:

**Table[2]**

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | FirstName | LastName |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 10 | Fred      | Ramirez  |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 20 | Willie    | James    |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 30 | Daniel    | Green    |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 40 | Matthew   | Walker   |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 50 | Aaron     | Wright   |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 60 | Richard   | Huey     |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 80 | Matthew   | Walker   |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

and

**Table[3]**

```
+----------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| Services | Fred ---10--- | Willie ---20--- | Daniel  ---30--- | Matthew  ---40--- | Aaron  ---50--- | Richard  ---60--- | Matthew  ---80--- |
+----------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| XXX      | 0             | 0               | 0                | 0                 | 0               | 0                 | 0                 |
+----------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| AAA      | 0             | 0               | 0                | 0                 | 0               | 0                 | 0                 |
+----------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| CCC      | 0             | 0               | 0                | 0                 | 0               | 0                 | 0                 |
+----------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| DDD      | 0             | 0               | 0                | 0                 | 0               | 0                 | 0                 |
+----------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| YYY      | 0             | 0               | 0                | 0                 | 0               | 0                 | 0                 |
+----------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

I need to get `LastName` from the `Table[2]` and make assign to  column name as `FirstName + LastName`

My code as follows,

```
int userID = 0;
string[] columnNameParts;
Result.GridViewDataTable = ds.Tables[3];
for (int currCol = 1; currCol < Result.GridViewDataTable.Columns.Count; currCol++)
{
    columnNameParts = Result.GridViewDataTable.Columns[currCol].ColumnName.Split(new string[] { "---" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    userID = int.Parse(columnNameParts[columnNameParts.Length - 1]);


    string columnName = ds.Tables[2].Select("Id = " + userID)[0]["FirstName"].ToString() + " " +
                                                           ds.Tables[2].Select("Id = " + userID)[0]["LastName"].ToString().Substring(0, 1);

    Result.GridViewDataTable.Columns[currCol].ColumnName = columnName;

}
```

With the above two tables data, I'm getting the following error.

```
A column named 'Matthew W' already belongs to this DataTable
```

It happen because Datatable have this (`Matthew | Walker`) record two times.

Once I setting a column name using this code,

```
string columnName = ds.Tables[2].Select("Id = " + userID)[0]["FirstName"].ToString() + " " +
                                                           ds.Tables[2].Select("Id = " + userID)[0]["LastName"].ToString().Substring(0, 1);
```

I need to check wether Datatable already consists that column name and if it's already exists I need to set `1` to end of the `LastName`. If same column name consists multiple time I need to add 1,2,3 likewise end of the LastName. As an example (**`Matthew W,Matthew W1,Matthew W2`**,) - how can I do it?

Comment: Why not have the colum "names" be (just) the id? That should be unique. And when _displaying_ the column headings, you could query the table by id and display the name(s) and way you like.

Comment: I agree with @Corak, why making your self confuse/hard if there is an easy and best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the exists column, this should work for you.

```
Result.GridViewDataTable.Columns.Contains(tmpColumnName)
```

Then, if you need the number after the columnName, you just put **index** after it. By the way, this snippet is not the best solution but I hope it can give you an idea of how to solve it. Hope this helps.

```
int userID = 0;
string[] columnNameParts;
Result.GridViewDataTable = ds.Tables[3];
for (int currCol = 1; currCol < Result.GridViewDataTable.Columns.Count; currCol++)
{
    columnNameParts = Result.GridViewDataTable.Columns[currCol].ColumnName.Split(new string[] { "---" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    userID = int.Parse(columnNameParts[columnNameParts.Length - 1]);

    string columnName = ds.Tables[2].Select("Id = " + userID)[0]["FirstName"].ToString()
        + " "
        + ds.Tables[2].Select("Id = " + userID)[0]["LastName"].ToString().Substring(0, 1);

    //index
    int n = 0;
    //Create new temporary columnName which will add to the Columns later 
    string tmpColumnName = columnName;
    //Check if column name is duplicate.
    while (Result.GridViewDataTable.Columns.Contains(tmpColumnName))
    {
        //Add 1 to index
        n++;
        //Create new name such as Matthew W1,Matthew W2,Daniel G1,Matthew W3,...
        tmpColumnName = columnName + n.ToString();
    }
    //Add new unique column name to Columns
    Result.GridViewDataTable.Columns[currCol].ColumnName = columnName;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried as your code. It's okay, but I need to set an already existing column name Matthew W,Matthew W1,Matthew W2,

Comment: @Adam I just made a change. By the way, this snippet is not the best solution but I hope it can give you an idea of how to solve it. Hope this helps.

Comment: suppose what happen If Tables[2] have another record same as `Daniel    | Green` . within that situation your code `n` value set incorrect value to name. please help me to avoid it

Comment: @Adam if you put the above snippet below `string columnName = ...`, I think it should work for you.

Comment: Sir, problem is when multiple same records are in datatable Ex:  `Matthew   | Walker` have multiple times and also `Daniel | Green` have two mutiple times

Comment: if you put `int n = 0;` inside your for-loop, then you will get `Matthew W | Matthew W1 | Daniel G | Matthew W2 | Daniel G1 | Matthew W3 | Daniel G2 | ....  |`.